# Can censoring of text in Android native Speech-to-Text API be turned off at the code level?

Tags: android, settings, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I saw this Q&A: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12578/how-the-f-to-stop-voice-to-text-from-censoring-profanity

So censoring behaviour of Android in general, and also Speech-to-Text can be turned off from the device settings. But can it be changed at the code level, i.e. can I write code in my app that will change this setting programmatically ? And if so, how?

Say i am looking specifically for profanities ,not to show the user but for background processing, if profanities are blocked by the user, will I be able to get the profanity in my code from Speech-to-text output?

Android's speech-to-text API does not have a parameter for turning off profanities, but can't I request the user to grant me 'write settings' permission `android.settings.WRITE_SETTINGS` and after acquiring that programmatically set the profanities settings to what i need it to be? I noticed that `android.settings.WRITE_SETTINGS` is not listed under 'Secure Settings'

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If a user wants to block profanity, you need to adhere to this.

Comment: @brandall Say i am looking specifically for profanities ,not to show the user but for background processing, if prfanities are blocked by the user, will I be able to get the profanity in my code from Speech-to-text output?

Answer (score 1):

Android's speech-to-text API does not have a parameter for turning off profanities. All the available parameters are in the [RecognizerIntent class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html).

Comment: yes, I understand, but can't I request the user to grant me 'write settings' permission `android.settings.WRITE_SETTINGS` and after acquiring that programmatically set the profanities settings to what i need it to be?

Comment: I noticed that `android.settings.WRITE_SETTINGS` is not listed under 'Secure Settings'